# implementing Queue Services in AV Audio Recorder using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-audio, avaudiorecorder

Is it possible to create a buffer concept similar to `AudioQueue` services in `AVRecorder` Framework.  In my application , i  need to capture the Audio buffer and send it over the Internet. The server connection part is done, but i wanted to know if there is a way to record the voice continuously in the foreground, and pass this audio buffer by buffer at the background to the server using `Swift`. 
Comments are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`AVAudioRecorder` records to a file, so you can't easily use it to stream audio data out of your app. `AVAudioEngine` on the other hand can call you back as it captures audio buffers:

```
var engine = AVAudioEngine()

func startCapturingBuffers() {
    let input = engine.inputNode!
    let bus = 0

    input.installTapOnBus(bus, bufferSize: 512, format: input.inputFormatForBus(bus)) { (buffer, time) -> Void in
        // buffer.floatChannelData contains audio data
    }

    try! engine.start()
}
```