# AVAudioSession on desktop?

Tags: objective-c, macos, avfoundation

On mac desktop I was trying to record system sound (and optionally microphone sound - but for starting I was just doing system sound).

I was following this guide - https://www.appcoda.com/ios-avfoundation-framework-tutorial/

However I keep getting:

```
 songifier.mm:8:9: fatal error: 'AVFoundation/AVAudioSession.h' file not found
```

## import

I am compiling with:

```
gcc -framework Cocoa -framework Foundation -framework Carbon -framework AppKit -framework AVFoundation -lstdc++ -o songifier songifier.mm
```

Does anyone know how to use `AVAudioSession` this from desktop to record system audio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `AVAudioSession` for the desktop - that code will have to be excluded from anything you compile for macos.

Comment: Ah shoots, ok thanks I'll look around for desktop alternative. Do you know how to record system audio with AVFoundation by chance? I'll accept your solution in 4 minutes (it says I cant accept for 4 minutes)

Comment: Accepted answer, I was trying to use `AVAudioCapture`, if you could guide me on this it would be awesome! I'm just learning C++ and simple projects like these really help me learn - https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/8214bf090c4fa861f9ff99a43c28b142

Comment: You can definitely record/capture audio (and much, much more) with `AVCaptureSession`, but if you just want to quickly get your hands on samples, `AVAudioEngine` is easy to get running: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39938979/22147

Comment: Thank you @Rythmic! I will look into it! So AVCaptureSession is different from AVAudioSession?

Comment: `AVCaptureSession` wraps up capturing from microphones, cameras and the screen (on osx), writing to files & previewing. `AVAudioSession` is for declaring your iOS app's audio requirements & scheduling audio hardware usage which can be taken away from you at any moment due to asynchronous events, like receiving a phone call.

Comment: Ohhh very very interesting thank you for sharing that @Rhythmic! I was trying to list all microphones and offer user to pick which to record from. And also record from screen. I'm having a tough time. Very much beginner, but these small exciting features really get me into it. May you please link me to some resources, I'm having difficult time. :(